# RadioGroup , clicking the same element again doesnt work

Tags: java, android, xml

Im trying to use RadioGroup for this demo example

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""

            tools:ignore="OnClick" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_cheese"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </RadioGroup>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="button1" />
```

and the Java codes like this:

```
firstCB.setText(firstCheckArray[i]);
secondCB.setText(secondCheckArray[i]);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        if (i<newStringArray.length-1){
        i++;
        firstCB.setText(firstCheckArray[i]);
        secondCB.setText(secondCheckArray[i]);

   }
  }
  });
```

the proplem that Im facing is when i increase (1) and next words group come, if I want to select the same radioButton it not selected until I select another RadioButton then I can select the same old one (in anther words, if i select the first choice, in the next step the first chioce in not selectable until I select other one then i can come back to the first choice

Answer (score 0):

You can set Radio button check by code in button1 click, like this

```
radioButton.setChecked(true);
```

And in your layout add

> android:checked="true"

It will check when show

```
 <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:checked="true"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />
```